# asp checkboxlist repeat direction

Tags: asp.net, css, checklistbox

I'm using checklistbox. I want to list all items like that
[image: checkboxlist]

But there 2 selection in repeatdirection. Only horizontal and vertical.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Text=" Monday "></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=" Tuesday "></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=" Wednesday "></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=" Thursday "></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=" Friday "></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=" Saturday "></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=" Sunday "></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

So I mean that half vertical and half horizontal. When row is full other items will be in next row.

How can I do that?

Comment: is that work for you ???

Comment: What do you mean about "Work"? It works, yes??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this `RepeatDirection`, `RepeatColumns`, and `RepeatLayout`:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
        RepeatColumns="2" RepeatLayout="Table" ...>
```

check more about property here : [CheckBoxList Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
.myGroupCheckBox{
            list-style:none;
            width:270px;            
        }
 .myGroupCheckBox li{
            display: inline;
        }
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" CssClass="myGroupCheckBox"
            RepeatLayout="UnorderedList">
            <asp:ListItem Text=" Monday "></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text=" Tuesday "></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text=" Wednesday "></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text=" Thursday "></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text=" Friday "></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text=" Saturday "></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text=" Sunday "></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```